# iOS Application Design - Cocoapods for layers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to figure out what best practices are for using private CocoaPods while creating a full application. I understand that CocoaPods are useful for pulling in open source projects and reusable libraries. What I'm wondering is if it is good design to create private CocoaPods for the layers of my application to create an additional layer of abstraction.

With this design, I would have private pods for Models, Controllers, Networking, Services, APIs, etc. For the most part, with the use of protocols, they would not have to depend on each other, and then I can pull them all in to my final project in the end.

Additionally, should there be multiple pods in each layer, for example, separate pods for view controllers that interact in each feature of the application? Should these be separate pods, or just subspecs (I don't think this is right)? Or should all my controllers just be put into one pod?

Does any of this seem like a good idea? Am I going to run into issues that I have not accounted for yet? Are the benefits that I think I'm going to get from this level of abstraction there, or does this sound like a waste of time?

Thanks for your opinions!

Answer (score 0):

You can try **git submodule** (very similar to **svn externals** if you are familiar with that). It is a perfect way of creating and managing sub-projects for you final big project. And you can create private repositories, which, is what you are looking for.

> Submodules allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a dedicated subdirectory of the source tree, always pointed at a particular commit.

Go over to the following link for more about how to use:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm already pretty sure I want to use CocoaPods for actually managing the submodules. I'm just trying to figure out what the best practices are for architecting them on iOS.

Comment: Okay. Sounds interesting~ I'll keep an eye on this question and wait with you.